# How to change the file type generated by eas in expo?

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

How to change the file type generated by eas in expo? I want .apk instead of .aab.

By default, eas adds an .aab file for me with the eas build command, but I need an .apk file type.

Answer (score 0):

in your `eas.json` file specify your build type by add `buildType`

```
{
   ...
   "preview": {
       "channel": "production",
       "ios": { ... }, 
       "android": {
         "buildType": "apk"
       }
   }
   ...
}
```

and then run `eas build --profile preview --platform android`